# How to skip Particular VF page in site

Tags: visualforce

I am using salesforce site which has 10 pages.  Based on conditions I want to skip 2 Vf pages.

If person chooses region = 'NA' and Relationship = 'Technology Solution' in page 1 after clicking the Continue button it should skip page 2 & page 3 and it should directly go to the page 4.

Comment: Probably yes, but you're not giving us nearly enough information to help you.  What order do users navigate the pages in now?  What are the conditions that would require a skip?

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response.   if person chooses region = 'NA' and Relationship = 'Technology Solution' in page 1 after clicking the Continue button it should skip page 2 & page 3 and it should directly go to the  page 4.

Comment: Also, you should edit your question to add that info in, not put it in comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your page 1 controller, assuming you have properties called `region` and `relationship` bound to the input fields and this `continue` action bound to the continue button:

```
public PageReference continue() {
    if (region == 'NA' && relationship == 'Technology Solution') {
        return Page.Page4;
    } else {
        return Page.Page2;
    } 
}
```